# How do I use ImageDownloadService to update button in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use a url as a source for the icon of a button like this

```
        Image placeholder = Image.createImage(Constants.IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER);
        propertyValue = jsonData.get("propertyValue").toString();
        propertyName =  jsonData.get("propertyName").toString();
        ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(propertyValue, 
                bImg,
                propertyValue,
                placeholder,
                ConnectionRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

bImg is a button, propertyValue contains the image url. Only the placeholder gets displayed and the button icon never changes. I also don't see any GET on the URL from the network monitor. 
I am sure I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this. The issue is that I was using the url as the cacheId. Now, I extract the filename from the url and use it as the cacheId and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The value of propertyValue should be a full URL including the http and server portions.

The value of the cacheId entry (the 3rd argument) should be propertyName or something like that.

You can also check out [URLImage](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/03/image-from-url-made-easy.html) which is slightly simpler for some cases.